# How to reshape data in custom function with dcast?

Tags: r, function, reshape, dcast

I have big sales data.frame with many columns - my future parameters for function (status, payment, delivery, source etc).

```
week / item.type / source / order / payment / delivery
31 / device / desktop / 222-111 / cash / courier
32 / tariff / mobile / 222-333 / card / courier
33 / tariff / desktop / 111444 / cash / courier
34 / tariff /  mobile / 333-555 / card / pickup
35 / device / desktop / 343-222 / cash / pickup
36 / number / desktop / 123-223 / card / pickup
```

I need universal function to make mini tables in format week ~ source, week ~ delivery, week ~ payment for weekly report.

```
device
=============
week / 31 / 32 / 33 / 34 / 35 / 36
mobile / 134/ 234 / 536 / 345 / 345 / 333
desktop / 231/ 356 / 755 / 261 / 333 / 222

tariff
=============
week / 31 / 32 / 33 / 34 / 35 / 36
mobile / 11 / 24 / 64 / 27 / 13 / 89
desktop / 62 / 92 / 83 / 41 / 76 / 55
```

Dcast without function is working.
Dplyr without dcast in function is wordking.
Both in function - refused.

```
ord <- function(df, gds, x1p, x2p) {
  res <- filter(df, str_detect(item.type, gds)) %>%
    dplyr::group_by_(x1p, x2p) %>%
    dplyr::summarise(orders = n_distinct(order)) %>%
    reshape2::dcast(df, x1p ~ x2p, sum)
}

orders_src <- ord(df.raw, 'device', 'week', 'source')
orders_src <- ord(df.raw, 'tariff', 'week', 'source')
```

Help me, please.

Comment: Just want to note that `reshape2` has been deprecated in favor of `tidyr` for a while now. If you're having trouble with keywords for searching for similar posts, try under tidyr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As we are passing the arguments as strings, one option is `group_by_at` and also in the `dcast`, create the formula with `paste`

```
ord <- function(df, gds, x1p, x2p) {
   filter(df, str_detect(item.type, gds)) %>%
     dplyr::group_by_at(vars(x1p, x2p)) %>%
     dplyr::summarise(orders = n_distinct(order)) %>%
     reshape2::dcast(., formula(paste(x1p,   x2p, sep= "~ ")),  sum)
  }
```